# How to run python scripts as test suites (running a set of tests together) using nose tests?

Tags: python, testing, nose

I have a about 50 automated scripts in Python and I would like to separate them as test suites - approx 5 in each meaning 10 suites. How do I achieve it using nosetests?

Comment: what is an 'automated script'?

Comment: Just a python script!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using:

```
> nosetests script1.py script2.py script3.py script4.py script5.py
> nosetests script3.py script4.py script5.py script6.py script7.py
> ...
```

If you organize your suits into folders you can run all tests in a folder in a single run.
Alternatively, you can use [attrib](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) plugin and mark individual tests as members of a particular suite with `@attr(suit='suit1')` and run them like this:

```
> nosetests -a suit='suit1'
```

Comment: I would like to use attrib.