# Running suites together with nosetests

Tags: python, testing, nosetests

Is there a way to run multiple test suites together using nostests/Python? This is using the "attr" keyword.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run python scripts as test suites (running a set of tests together) using nose tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742495/how-to-run-python-scripts-as-test-suites-running-a-set-of-tests-together-using)

Comment: No its not a duplicate. That thread says how to run them as suites but I want to run my 10 suites together but as suites not as individual tests.

Comment: Providing example will help